# AWS CloudFormation where will UserData be stored?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

if I have a AWS CloudFormation template using UserData block containing script block to be executed, for example:

```
"UserData": {
    "Fn::Base64": {
        "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
                "#!/bin/bash\n",
                "apt-get update\n",
                "apt-get -y upgrade\n",
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

After the instance is created,

1. I assume that this script block will be saved somewhere to be execute?
2. If so, where can I find this script on the EC2 instance?
3. Will AWS remove this temporary script after stack is created successfully?

I could not find they mention in the doc.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user-data for an instance is available for any process on the instance to retrieve at this location:

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data
```

The DNS name "instance-data" resolves to that IP address, so if you trust DNS to be up, you can also use the easier to remember:

```
http://instance-data/latest/user-data
```

Here are the Amazon docs:

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html

Answer (score 4):

in `/var/lib/cloud/data/scripts/` folder

Answer (score 3):

1. I assume that this script block will be saved somewhere to be execute?

Yes, Cloudfomration Stores the userdata whatever you sent inside "UserData" block.

2. If so, where can I find this script on the EC2 instance?

You can find Userdata @ `/var/lib/cloud/instance/userdata.txt`
and Userdata logs @ `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

3. Will AWS remove this temporary script after stack is created successfully?
   No, AWS won't remove the userdata script after stack is created. You can use it for debugging purpose.

FYI : If you use custom AMI, you can see the original instance userdata and current userdata's also in `/var/lib/cloud/instances/*`. Looks like AWS never removing the userdata histories.

Hope this helps for basic understanding.